# Multiple Columns in CV

Tags: multicol

I am designing CV using latex. I want to implement the following section but unable to find any way. Please help me out.I am using the following template : https://www.overleaf.com/project/5caf73097bba5b0aeab82461[image]

Comment: Your link is off site !! your link requires password !! your link has no name to search on !! your link..... is not apiece of header we can work with Welcome and please supply the requested MWE

Answer (score 1):

You could try multicol package.
Add in your preamble

```
\usepackage{multicol}
```

Then,

```
\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize}
\item ITW 1
\item ITW 2
\item and so on.
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: I have made a new .tex file and pasted your code but in this way I lost font size, style and color. The text that is appearing on the screen is not the same.

Comment: Now you understand how it works. You don't need to create a new file. You just need to modify your file to preserve fonts, colours, etc..
The preamble is the part of the file before \begin{document}
Then you can modify the section of your relevant courses like was stated...